# Which selector to write in rvest in R to extract information from google websearch?

Tags: r, selector, rvest

I am trying to download content of google websearch that is in 
`<h3 class="r">` as on image below

I've tried to write such selectors in R, using `rvest` package but with no result.
Anyone knows how should the selector look like?

```
> library(rvest)
> 
> googleContent <- html("https://www.google.pl/#q=wiadomosci") %>% 
+    html_nodes( "h3[class=r]" )
> googleContent
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
> googleContent <- html("https://www.google.pl/#q=wiadomosci") %>% 
+    html_nodes( "h3.r" )
> googleContent
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

I've tried other packages but I don't like the messy code...
(changed code from this [article](https://tonybreyal.wordpress.com/2011/11/07/web-scraping-google-urls/))

```
> # load packages
> library(RCurl)
> library(XML)
> library(dplyr)
> get_google_page_urls <- function(u) {
+    # read in page contents
+    html <- getURL(u)
+    
+    # parse HTML into tree structure
+    doc <- htmlParse(html)
+    
+    # extract url nodes using XPath. Originally I had used "//a[@href][@class='l']" until the google code change.
+    links <- xpathApply(doc, "//h3//a[@href]", function(x) xmlAttrs(x)[[1]])
+    
+    # free doc from memory
+    free(doc)
+    
+    # ensure urls start with "http" to avoid google references to the search page
+    links <- grep("http://", links, fixed = TRUE, value=TRUE)
+    return(links)
+ }
> 
> u <- "http://www.google.pl/search?aq=f&gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wiadomosci"
>  get_google_page_urls(u) %>% grep( pattern = "/url", value = TRUE) %>% strsplit( "?q=") %>%
+    lapply( function(element){ strsplit( element[2], ".pl" )[[1]][1] } ) %>%
+    unlist() %>% paste0(".pl") %>% unique()
[1] "http://wiadomosci.onet.pl"   "http://www.tvn24.pl"         "http://tvnwarszawa.tvn24.pl"
[4] "http://wiadomosci.wp.pl"     "http://warszawa.gazeta.pl"   "http://wiadomosci.gazeta.pl"
[7] "http://wiadomosci.tvp.pl"    "http://www.se.pl"
```

Does this might help somehow?
I don't understand this functionality because the documentation is very poor

```
search <- html_form(html("https://www.google.com"))[[1]]


set_values(search, q = "My little pony")
```

[image: example]

Comment: In `bing` it works with `html_nodes('#b_content')`.

Comment: bing is a search engine like google and yahoo.

Comment: Ok what does it have in common with google question :)?

Comment: Nothing in common. But, it gives the same output that you are looking for.